# open with not creating and writing file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am following a tutorial (Beautiful Soup) and I can't seem to get open with to create a .txt file as I am getting this error:
with open(f'posts/{index}.txt', 'w+') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'posts/1.txt'. I tried looking up different solutions to my problem currently running python 3.9. Is there another step I need to correct this issue?

[image: IDE Pycharm]

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour] and read [ask] to improve, [edit] and format your questions. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interpreter isn't finding the directory "posts" in your current working directory.  If it exists, you are not in its parent directory.  Try using the full path, e.g. `rf'C:\users\myuser\posts\{index}.txt'` or `rf'~/posts/{index}.txt'` on linux.

Or, if it doesnt't exist, add these lines:

```
import os
os.mkdir('posts')
```

You can find your current working directory this way:

```
import os
os.path.abspath('.')
```

Comment: The import solved the issue, thanks.